# Laravel - Append to query

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I'm building a query in laravel with a lot of optional parameters that **might** be passed through in the GET request.

JS:

```
$url = "/search/?q=" + $searchText;

if ($subchanSearch) {
    $url = $url + "&subchan=" + $subchan;
}

if ($includeNSFW) {
    $url = $url + "&incl_nsfw=1"
}

if ($politicsOnly) {
    $url = $url + "&pol=1"
}
/etc. etc. for 10+ other parameters
```

So let's say this is the default query:

```
$submissions = Submission::search($request->q)
            ->where('removed',0)
            ->where('nsfw', 0)
            ->paginate(10);
```

But some parameters get passed, and now the query needs to get submissions where subchan_id = 37, and NSFW can now be 0 or 1, etc.

I can't exactly do something like

```
 ->where('subchan', any)
```

until specified otherwise.

What's the most elegant way to build such a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`conditional cluases`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses). This will allow you to add more stuff to your query if an expression is `true`.

So, following your example, you would have something like:

```php
$submissions = Submission::search($request->q)
    ->where('removed',0)
    ->when($request->input('subchan'), function ($query, $subchan_id) {
        return $query->where('subchan_id', $subchan_id)->where('nsfw', 1);
    }, function ($query) {
        return $query->where('nsfw', 0);
    })
    ->paginate(10);
```

This way, if there is a `subchan` in your URL, it will use it and change NSFW to 1 (this is an example), but if there is no `subchan` in the URL, it will default to the second query -> `nsfw = 0`.

You can use `->when` all the time you want with any expression you want, just use it before `->paginate` as it will return a `LenghtAwarePaginator` class and not a `Builder` class.

Comment: This actually doesn't work because Laravel scout doesn't allow for anything more than a numeric where clause. Wow.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scout#where-clauses

Comment: Do not confuse `where` with `search`, there should be no problem as I stated, try it and then see what happens. Also, you never said you were using Laravel Scout...

Comment: I didn't think scout would change anything, but it seems that the moment I use search it uses the Scout builder. I tried your answer and it didn't work, though i'm sure it would work with a normal query.